# Trigger JSF validation using ajax after focus lost

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf

How do you trigger validation on an input component when the component loses focus using ajax instead of waiting for the form to be manually submitted?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put a `<f:ajax event="blur">` in the `UIInput` component which re-renders a `<h:message>` associated with the component in question.

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" required="true">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="fooMessage" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="fooMessage" />
```

See also [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Tomcat - the view](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#CreateJSFHelloWorldInEclipseTheView) and [finetuning validation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#FinetuningValidation)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.validateValue}">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="valueError"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:outputText id="valueError" value="#{bean.valueErrorMessage}" style="color: red;" />
```

If the user changes the value in your input component you can validate it with your valueChangeListener. If the user then moves to another input component the ouputText component will be rendered. There you can display a message if the validation failed.

Comment: The event name in this answer is however wrong. It shouldn't be prefixed with `on`. Plus, you'd normally like to use `<h:message>` to display validation messages.

Comment: I tried to correct it but stackoverflow did not allow just changing two letters in a post. they required 5 so I left it like that

Comment: Third thing is that a `valueChangeListener` isn't intented to do validation. Use a normal validator.

Comment: For correctness and future reference, I think BalusC's answer is much more correct