# Validate input onblur/on focus lost

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces

i am making email validation for an input with regular expression as follows:

```
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{settingsBean.aFriendEmail}" required="true" label="Email" validatorMessage="#{settingsBean.aFriendEmail} is not valid">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
</h:inputText>
<p:message for="email" />
```

and i was wondering how to make this validation **onblur/on focus lost** for that input.
please advise how to accomplish that, thanks.

also, i want to restrict the valid domains to be .com, .net, .org 
any advises about that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF 2.0 Trigger validation after focus lost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787965/jsf-2-0-trigger-validation-after-focus-lost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `<f:ajax>` which is hooked on `blur` event and updates the message on complete.

```
<h:inputText id="email" ...>
    ...
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="emailMessage" />
</h:inputText>
<p:message id="emailMessage" for="email" />
```

Restricting the email domain by regex is a separate question completely unrelated to JSF.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your `validatorMessage` is not right.

```
validatorMessage="#{settingsBean.aFriendEmail} is not valid"
```

The model value is never updated when the validation has failed, so this would **always** print the initial value, which may be null/empty. You should instead display the [component's submitted value](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#getSubmittedValue%28%29).

```
validatorMessage="#{component.submittedValue} is not valid"
```